# Logic for tracking entity framework property value changes in MVC

Tags: entity-framework

I think I am missing something in my understanding of tracking property value changes in entity framework.

I have an application where i store service requests. Whenever a team value in changed in the service request record, I want to create a team history record in  a  related teamhistory entity.

I have created the app in MVC using the standard scaffolding for controllers and views.
In the (post)edit task in  the controller, the standard logic generated has the following code

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(serviceRequest).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(serviceRequest);
```

I have modified that to include the creating of the teamhistory record and an individualhistory record for individual assigned within team. The code for creating these related records work, BUT i want these records only created when the values on team or member(individual) change from what they were previously.

So far the conditions i have specified due not trigger this correctly because I havent gotten the condition right. Below is  the current code:

//string teamorig = db.Entry(serviceRequest).Property(u => u.Team).OriginalValue.ToString();
    //string teamcurr = db.Entry(serviceRequest).Property(u => u.Team).CurrentValue.ToString();
    //if (teamorig != teamcurr)

```
var TeamIsModified = db.Entry(serviceRequest).Property(u => u.Team).IsModified;
if (TeamIsModified)
            {
                serviceRequest.TeamAssignmentHistories.Add(new TeamAssignmentHistory()
                {
                    DateAssigned = DateTime.Now,
                    AssignedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                    ServiceRequest = serviceRequest.Id,
                    Team = serviceRequest.Team
                });
            }
            //=========================================================================================


            // if individual assigned has changed add individual history record========================

            var IndividualIsModified = db.Entry(serviceRequest).Property(u => u.Member).IsModified;
            if (IndividualIsModified)
            {
                serviceRequest.IndividualAssignmentHistories.Add(new IndividualAssignmentHistory()
                {
                    DateAssigned = DateTime.Now,
                    AssignedBy = User.Identity.Name,
                    ServiceRequest = serviceRequest.Id,
                    AssignedTo = serviceRequest.Member.Value,
                });
            }
            //===========================================================================================
```

The var teamismodified logic doesnt work. When I save the page without making any changes on it- the logic kicks off because in debugging it thinks the field has been modified.

When I comment out that code and uncomment the code above it for original and currentvalues- ie the teamorig and teamcurr logic, teamcurr and teamorig have the same values in debug, even when they have been forced into a change on the save in the MVC view page. Because they have the same values, the if condition is false so the  team history record is not created.

The above code has been sandwiched in between

db.Entry(serviceRequest).State = EntityState.Modified;

and
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
statements.

What am I not understanding about entity framework tracking changes in mvc? Why does think its modified when i make not changes to team, and why are teamorig and teamcurr the same when I do make the changes?

Any advice would be welcome. Thanks

Comment: My question may be a little bit convoluted. If that is the case I will attempt to clarify.Thanks.

Comment: My question may be a little bit convoluted. If that is the case I will attempt to clarify.Thanks. When in edit more with MVC controller and MVC edit view page that have been scaffolded in the standard way- what is the if statement logic for determining whether one of the fields in one of the entities has changed. On the view its a drop down list. How do i track in the controller code that the dropdownlist values has changed on save?

Comment: Since standard scaffolding creates the the EntityState.Modified statement above, i dont think that checking whether the individual field is modified works and neither does the original and current value comparisons. Because  I think the EntityState.Modified statement changes all fields to 'is modified' and sets the original values to current-correct?  How do I get around this in MVC edit controller and view?